# Como pegar id de usuário numa sessão?

Tags: java, session, jsp, servlet

Estou fazendo um projeto utilizando jsp e servlet, eu preciso que quando um usuario faça login, o id dele fique guardado na sessão, para que com este id, o sistema saiba que esse usuario de id tal, está fazendo alteração dos seus dados (Exemplo, alteração de telefone). Como eu poderia fazer isso?

Controle:

```
public void login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException, SQLException, ServletException{
    String login = request.getParameter("usuario");
    String senha = request.getParameter("senha");

    Usuario usuario = new Usuario();
    usuario.setEmail(login);
    usuario.setSenha(senha);

    UsuarioDAO usuarioDAO = new UsuarioDAO();
    Usuario usuarioAutenticado = usuarioDAO.validar(usuario);

    if (usuarioAutenticado !=null){
        HttpSession sessaoUsuario = request.getSession();
        sessaoUsuario.setAttribute("usuario",usuarioAutenticado);
        sessaoUsuario.setMaxInactiveInterval(10);
        response.sendRedirect("home.html");
    }else{
        response.sendRedirect("erroLogin.html");
    }
}
```

DAO:

```
public Usuario validar(Usuario usuario) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException{

    Connection con = FabricaConexao.getConexao();

    Usuario us= null;

    PreparedStatement comando = con.prepareStatement("select * from usuario where email = ? and senha=?");
    comando.setString(1,usuario.getEmail());
    comando.setString(2,usuario.getSenha());

    ResultSet resultado = comando.executeQuery();

    if (resultado.next()){
        us=new Usuario();
        us.setEmail(resultado.getString("email"));
        us.setSenha(resultado.getString("senha"));
        //us.setPerfilAcesso(resultado.getString("perfil_acesso"));

    }

    con.close();
    return us;
}
```

HTML:

```
<form role="form" action="login" method="POST" >
            <label for="usuario">Usuario (e-mail): </label><br>
            <input type="text" name="usuario" id=usuario required><br>
            <label for="senha">Senha </label><br>
            <input type="password" name="senha" id=senha required><br>

            <br><input type="submit" class="btn btn-login" value="Login">
            <br><a href=cadastroConta.html>Nao possui conta? Click aqui</a>
        </form>
```

Comment: `session.setAttribute("usuario", id);` onde o **"usuario"** é o atributo que você chama na hora de verificar qual usuário esta na `Session`. Foi assim que fiz em uma aplicação que precisei salvar o usuário na Session

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Celina, você já está com o ID do usuário salvo na sessão.

Veja bem, quando você coloca:

```
sessaoUsuario.setAttribute("usuario",usuarioAutenticado);
```

Dai, a partir disso, você pode recuperar o ID do usuário a qualquer momento, seja nas Servlets, seja nas JSP. Você pode fazer assim:

**Servlets**

```
Usuario usuario = (Usuario)request.getAttribute("usuario");
Long id = usuario.getId(); //Aqui você ja tem o id do usuário
```

**JSP** (Utilizando JSTL)

```
${sessionScope.usuario.id}
```

Por questões de segurança, você pode colocar apenas o ID, como o @R.Santos sugeriu:

```
request.getSession().setAttribute("idUsuario", usuarioAutenticado.getId());
```

Uma vez que é comum o objeto usuário conter um atributo `senha` por exemplo.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Eu testei aqui e deu certo. A ideia é fazer com que a jsp recupere o id do usuario. Isto eu consegui. Obrigada! Mas só mais uma dúvida, utilizei ${sessionScope.usuario.id} na jsp, agora como eu consigo mandar esse id para que eu possa recupera-lo numa servlet (por exemplo, este usuario de id tal vai cadastrar um endereço)?

Comment: O mais legal de te usar session, é que você não precisa "mandar" para uma Servlet. O que você pode fazer é recuperar ele na Servlet direto. (Lembre-se que de que o escopo Session é para todas as páginas de uma única sessão).

Fica algo assim:

`Usuario u = (Usuario) request.getSession().getAttribute("usuario");
u.getId(); //aqui voce tem o ID, faça o que quiser com ele.`

Comment: deu certo aqui. Obrigada!